# jQuery $.post() deferred functions not working

Tags: jquery, post

Is this how the $.post() function is supposed to work?  I have this code:

```
$.post('doesnt_exist.inc').done(function(data) {
    alert(data); // data = Full page HTML
}).fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
    alert(error); // Not triggered
});

$.post('exists.txt').done(function(data) {
    alert(data); // Not triggered
}).fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
    alert(error); // error = Not Allowed
});

$.post('doesnt_exist.txt').done(function(data) {
    alert(data); // data = Full page HTML
}).fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
    alert(error); // Not triggered
});
```

My goal is basically to try to read a file on the server and to alert of an error/failure if it does not exist (file is in the same path or different on the same domain).  Is $.post() not the right jQuery function to use?

Comment: `$.get()` would be better. `$.post()` is for running scripts on the server.

Comment: ok.  with $.get('exists.txt'), that works.  However, if the txt file does not exist, it triggers .done() with the full page HTML.  The other 2 still triggers .done() with the full page HTML.

Comment: It sounds like your webserver is configured to send a fallback file for `.txt` files. If the webserver sends something, the browser won't know it's an error.

Comment: Check the console -- if you don't see an error there, it won't trigger `.fail()`.

Comment: check if the server returns a proper 404 error and check for that

Comment: ahhh.the webserver eh. ok..let me check my nginx.conf file.

Comment: https://www.example.com/invalid_folder/invalid_file.txt --> No input file specified.

Comment: https://www.example.com/valid_folder/invalid_file.txt --> Seems like it loads index.php automatically.

Comment: The "Not Allowed" failure on a valid file using $.post() also puzzles me.  Is it the configuration of my web server?

Comment: The browser console shows no errors nor warnings.

Comment: I would have thought that $.get() and $.post() would do the same thing, but $.get() did managed to read the txt file while $.post() failed with a "Now Allowed" error message.  So my web server is configured correctly to access any files (I tested with different file extensions).

Comment: Looking further into the returned error message, it looks like using $.post() looking up a valid file and we get error "Not Allowed", it is coming from nginx and is error 405.  I'll look into that a bit more.